# Ajax request returns bad request (400) on POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to send this ajax call which is failing. I cant really undertand why is it so.

can somebody please take a look at my code.

The call is not even hitting the controller code(it seems to me) although in the fireBug I can see the payload is getting transformed correctly.

**jquery**

```
function userAdd(){
    var array2=new Array();
    var array1=new Array();

    var value2=$('input:checkbox.value2').each(function () {
        if(this.checked){
           array2.push($(this).attr('itemLabel'));
        }
      });

    var value1=$('input:checkbox.value1').each(function () {
        if(this.checked)
        array1.push( $(this).attr('itemLabel'));
      });

    var report = ({
                    user:user,
                    address:$("#address").val(),                
                    regimesRemove:array2,
                    regimesReport:array1

                });


        jQuery.ajax( {
                    async : false,
                    cache : false, 
                    url : "/myapp/user/addUser",
                    type : 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                    dataType : 'json', 
                    data:JSON.stringify(report),
                    success : function(data) {
                         if(data.errorMessage == undefined){
                            alert(data.errorMessage);
                            window.location.reload();
                        }else if(data.errorMessage !=''){
                            alert(data.errorMessage); 
                            window.location.href="/myapp/user";
                        else 
                            window.location.href="/myapp/user";
                    },
                    complete : function(request, status) {
                     if (status == undefined || status == "error" || status == "parsererror") {

                            alert("Error with status: "+status);
                            window.location.href="/myapp/user/";
                        } else if (status != 'success'){
                            alert("error with status: "+status);
                            alert('error in searching Invalid or submitted records: '+status);
                }
        }
    }); 
}
```

**Java**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody Report updateRulesForRequest(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody Report report){



     }
```

**log**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/addUser
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length:1417
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Server:Jetty(7.0.2.v20100331)
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:335
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:timezoneOffset=330; timezoneOffset=330; JSESSIONID=16ukve3dwiqt6
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/myapp/selectUser/getUser?Id=C9067134CA9711E56095E83935B46D68
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: HTTP status code 400 means that there is something wrong with your request. Could you please copy paster your ajax request from firebug here? That would help to identify the problem.
Also, your controller class has been mapped to `/user`, right?

Comment: yes right! it  has been mapped to /user

Comment: Did your request contain any `'` or `"` ?

Comment: Does `Report`exactly match the data structure you send to the server? `async : false` is really bad and `cache : false` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url you are using to hit the controller's method is correct.
Try this with the updated `url` value in the ajax request.

```
jQuery.ajax( {
                async : false,
                cache : false, 
                url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath }/myapp/user/addUser",
                type : 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                dataType : 'json', 
                data:JSON.stringify(report),
                success : function(data) {
                     if(data.errorMessage == undefined){
                        alert(data.errorMessage);
                        window.location.reload();
                    }else if(data.errorMessage !=''){
                        alert(data.errorMessage); 
                        window.location.href="/myapp/user";
                    else 
                        window.location.href="/myapp/user";
                },
                complete : function(request, status) {
                 if (status == undefined || status == "error" || status == "parsererror") {

                        alert("Error with status: "+status);
                        window.location.href="/myapp/user/";
                    } else if (status != 'success'){
                        alert("error with status: "+status);
                        alert('error in searching Invalid or submitted records: '+status);
            }
    }
```

Comment: try it with the updated url ${pageContext.request.contextPath }/myapp/user/addUser

Comment: Try updating the error from the console with logs to in your question